# how to display data that has 2 possibilities in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Please help
I want to display an ID that has 2 item categories, for example showing an id that has 'apple' and 'pen' items so that the results appear ID 1

[image: Table]

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review the guide for asking good questions on the site. Also, please refrain from posting links to screenshots; instead, post your code directly into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using a self join and making each table alias relate to a specific item:

```
SELECT i.id
FROM items i
JOIN items j USING id
WHERE i.item="apple" AND j.item="pen"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
select ID from items group by ID having count(ID)> 1
```

Which will return all `ID` values appearing more than once.